# Multiple column Join and distinct

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Can someone please clarify how exactly are these joined together, I am aware of how joins in SQL works, but this seems quite confusing. I am confused how the query is connected to each other, I tried to break down the query and run them them individually, but it fails, I would be really thankful for any suggestions on this.

```
select distinct
[Mandant_5].[Zahlungsabgleich].[lvRechnungZahlungszuordnung].[cBestellnummer] as [OrderNumber],
[Mandant_5].[Zahlungsabgleich].[lvRechnungZahlungszuordnung].[dBestelldatum] as [OrderDate],
[Mandant_5].[RM].[lvRetoureLieferscheinPos].[cArtNr] as [Artikelnummer],
[Mandant_5].[RM].[lvRetoureLieferscheinPos].[cName] as [Bezeichnung], --not required
[Mandant_5].[dbo].[tArtikel].[cASIN] as [ASIN],
[Mandant_5].[DbeS].[vLieferscheinPosition].[fAnzahl] as [Menge],

[Mandant_5].[Rechnung].[tRechnungPositionEckdaten].[fVKNettoGesamt] as [Netto-VK (Gesamt)],-- not required
([Mandant_5].[Rechnung].[tRechnungPositionEckdaten].[fVKNettoGesamt]/[Mandant_5].[DbeS].[vLieferscheinPosition].[fAnzahl]) as [Netto-VK], -- not required
[Mandant_5].[Rechnung].[tRechnungPositionEckdaten].[fVKBrutto] as [Brutto-VK],
[Mandant_5].[SCX].[vOrderShippingShippedFrom].[cCountryIso] as [Country],
[Mandant_5].[Zahlungsabgleich].[lvRechnungZahlungszuordnung].[cZahlungsartbezeichnung] as [Zahlungsart],-- not required
[Mandant_5].[Zahlungsabgleich].[lvRechnungZahlungszuordnung].[fBetrag] as [Betrag] -- question

from [Mandant_5].[Rechnung].[tRechnungPositionEckdaten]

join [Mandant_5].[Rechnung].[tRechnungLieferscheinPosition]
on [Mandant_5].[Rechnung].[tRechnungPositionEckdaten].[kRechnungPosition] = [Mandant_5].[Rechnung].[tRechnungLieferscheinPosition].[kRechnungPosition]

join [Mandant_5].[DbeS].[vLieferscheinPosition]
on [Mandant_5].[Rechnung].[tRechnungLieferscheinPosition].[kLieferscheinPosition] = [Mandant_5].[DbeS].[vLieferscheinPosition].[kLieferscheinPos]

join [Mandant_5].[RM].[lvRetoureLieferscheinPos]
on [Mandant_5].[RM].[lvRetoureLieferscheinPos].[kLieferscheinPos] = [Mandant_5].[Rechnung].[tRechnungLieferscheinPosition].[kLieferscheinPosition]

join [Mandant_5].[dbo].[tArtikel]
on [Mandant_5].[dbo].[tArtikel].[cArtNr] = [Mandant_5].[RM].[lvRetoureLieferscheinPos].[cArtNr]

join [Mandant_5].[SCX].[vOrderShippingShippedFrom]
on [Mandant_5].[SCX].[vOrderShippingShippedFrom].[kAuftrag] = [Mandant_5].[RM].[lvRetoureLieferscheinPos].[kAuftrag]

join [Mandant_5].[Statistik].[vRechnung]
on [Mandant_5].[Statistik].[vRechnung].[kAuftrag] = [Mandant_5].[RM].[lvRetoureLieferscheinPos].[kAuftrag]

join [Mandant_5].[Zahlungsabgleich].[lvRechnungZahlungszuordnung]
on [Mandant_5].[Zahlungsabgleich].[lvRechnungZahlungszuordnung].[cRechnungsnummer] = [Mandant_5].[Statistik].[vRechnung].[cRechnungsnr]
```

Comment: First recommendation, use table aliases to make your query clearer, as it stands its a wall of text which is very difficult to view. And don't use 3-part naming for tables at all unless you have a very good reason to. And definitely do not use 4-part column naming. Sort that out and your query will be a fraction of its current size.

Comment: Second thing, it really not clear what you are asking, the joins seem straightforward, they join one table onto another using a a column match, what exactly do you not understand about that?

Comment: And MySQL <> SQL Server - please correct your tags.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: That query is sql-server syntax (not MySQL) - please don't use tags that aren't directly relevant to the question. You may edit the tags (there is a link beside the tags for this.)

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow sowmya! have you taken a [tour] and learn [ask]? it would be **very helpful** if you could make [mcve]. i hope you can take a small detour on sql `join` concept (there are a lot of content in this regard out there) to improve your understanding on the matter. also, depends on how did you "run them individually" may result in a running query or a failure - if you "break down" a car by removing its engine then the car won't run.

Comment: If you don't understand what this query is doing but do understand how joins work I would debug by removing(by commenting out) all joins and their selected columns together with the distinct clause then start adding them back in again running the query after every join is added until you get your head around it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm certain that the complex table references make reading that query much harder than it could be. So to help I suggest (even if only for your own comprehension) to grant each table an alias which will help reduce the number of multi-part table/column references.

e.g.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 

      PositionEckdaten.[fVKNettoGesamt]                 AS [Netto-VK (Gesamt)]
 -- , PositionEckdaten.[fVKBrutto]                      AS [Brutto-VK]
      
 --   tRechnungLieferscheinPosition                     -- no columns from this table

    , vLieferscheinPosition.[fAnzahl]                   AS [Menge]
 -- , (PositionEckdaten.[fVKNettoGesamt] 
 --     / vLieferscheinPosition].[fAnzahl])             AS [Netto-VK]

    , LieferscheinPos.[cArtNr]                          AS [Artikelnummer]
    , LieferscheinPos.[cName]                           AS [Bezeichnung]
    
 -- , tArtikel.[cASIN]                                  AS [ASIN]
    
    , ShippedFrom.[cCountryIso]                         AS [Country]
    
 --   vRechnung                                         -- no columns from this table
 
    , zuordnung.[cBestellnummer]                        AS [OrderNumber]
    , zuordnung.[dBestelldatum]                         AS [OrderDate]
    , zuordnung.[cZahlungsartbezeichnung]               AS [Zahlungsart]
 -- , zuordnung.[fBetrag]                               AS [Betrag]
    
FROM [Mandant_5].[Rechnung].[tRechnungPositionEckdaten]           as PositionEckdaten
JOIN [Mandant_5].[Rechnung].[tRechnungLieferscheinPosition]       as tRechnungLieferscheinPosition ON PositionEckdaten.[kRechnungPosition] = tRechnungLieferscheinPosition.[kRechnungPosition]  
JOIN [Mandant_5].[DbeS].[vLieferscheinPosition]                   as vLieferscheinPosition         ON tRechnungLieferscheinPosition.[kLieferscheinPosition] = vLieferscheinPosition.[kLieferscheinPos]
JOIN [Mandant_5].[RM].[lvRetoureLieferscheinPos]                  as LieferscheinPos               ON tRechnungLieferscheinPosition.[kLieferscheinPosition] = LieferscheinPos].[kLieferscheinPos]  
JOIN [Mandant_5].[dbo].[tArtikel]                                 as tArtikel                      ON LieferscheinPos.[cArtNr] = tArtikel.[cArtNr]
JOIN [Mandant_5].[SCX].[vOrderShippingShippedFrom]                as ShippedFrom                   ON LieferscheinPos.[kAuftrag] = ShippedFrom].[kAuftrag]
JOIN [Mandant_5].[Statistik].[vRechnung]                          as vRechnung                     ON LieferscheinPos.[kAuftrag] = vRechnung.[kAuftrag]
JOIN [Mandant_5].[Zahlungsabgleich].[lvRechnungZahlungszuordnung] as zuordnung                     ON vRechnung.[cRechnungsnr] = zuordnung.[cRechnungsnummer]
```

Also, by some extra formatting (such as alignment of column aliases) it's easier to read. I've also re-arranged the selected columns to be in the order of joining the tables.

Within the joins, I have also rearranged the order after ON. e.g.

```
from t1
join t2 on t1.id = t2.pk -- I prefer to list the prerequisite table first in each join
```

When arranged in this way I believe you can more easily see the relationships

```
FROM ...as PositionEckdaten
JOIN ...as tRechnungLieferscheinPosition ON PositionEckdaten.[kRechnungPosition] = tRechnungLieferscheinPosition.[kRechnungPosition]  
JOIN ...as vLieferscheinPosition         ON tRechnungLieferscheinPosition.[kLieferscheinPosition] = vLieferscheinPosition.[kLieferscheinPos]
JOIN ...as LieferscheinPos               ON tRechnungLieferscheinPosition.[kLieferscheinPosition] = LieferscheinPos].[kLieferscheinPos]  
JOIN ...as tArtikel                      ON LieferscheinPos.[cArtNr] = tArtikel.[cArtNr]
JOIN ...as ShippedFrom                   ON LieferscheinPos.[kAuftrag] = ShippedFrom].[kAuftrag]
JOIN ...as vRechnung                     ON LieferscheinPos.[kAuftrag] = vRechnung.[kAuftrag]
JOIN ...as zuordnung                     ON vRechnung.[cRechnungsnr] = zuordnung.[cRechnungsnummer]
```

Overall the query seems relatively straitghtforward, just 8 tables inner joined together (so no outer joins to consider) and all but 2 tables are directly referenced in the select clause. The 2 unreferenced tables are necessary to join other tables.

Not much else to say except that `select distinct` of several columns for 8 joined tables may not be optimal.